# htaccess Rewrite rule for anything after the domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a one page website that just has a switch that replaces some content with a local town names.

The normal domain.com will go to index.php, but I want anything after the domain to be passed in the GET query.

So **domain.com/nottingham** would go to **index.php?town=nottingham**

I have around 300 town names, so I dont ant to hardcode them all so I'm trying to get the **$1** to pass the value and it doesn't seem to work.

I've got the following in my .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])$   /index.php?town=$1 [NC,L]`

`ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`

But when I try domain.com/townname I get "Warning: Undefined array key "town" in..." So I assume thats missing my rewriterule and gonig to the 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include a quantifier in your pattern - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` means allow for *one* character out of this character group. And since you anchored your pattern at the start and end, it would match when you requested `domain.com/t`, but not with any path component longer than that.

Add the `+` quantifier after the character group, to say "a character matching this group, one or more times":

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$   /index.php?town=$1 [NC,L]
```